# wsimport <property> is already defined

Tags: java, xml, xsd, wsdl, xjb

I'm dealing with a remote WSDL in which some XSD are invoked twice. 
I'm trying to use xjb binding to get rid of

> 'EndpointReference' is already defined
>     riga 22 di file:...../wsdl/ws-addr.xsd
>
> (related to above error) the first definition appears here
>     riga 22 di file:...../wsdl/www.w3.org/2006/03/addressing/ws-addr.xsd

This is part of the XSD

```
<xs:element name="EndpointReference" type="tns:EndpointReferenceType"/>
<xs:complexType name="EndpointReferenceType" mixed="false">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="tns:AttributedURIType"/>
        <xs:element ref="tns:ReferenceParameters" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element ref="tns:Metadata" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

and this is the jxb binding

```
<bindings schemaLocation="wsdl/ws-addr.xsd" version="1.0">
    <!-- Customise the package name -->
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.example.schema"/>
    </schemaBindings>

    <!-- rename the value element -->
    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='EndpointReference']">
        <property name="EndpointReference1"/>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

How to rename the twice declared element?
Otherwise, is there a way to remap the other XSD?